# Rewrite filter into pipe operators in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I am very new to Elixir and am trying to rewite this:

```
kids = ["Mike", "Paula", "Julia", "Phil"]
Enum.filter(kids, fn(n) -> String.contains? n, "i" end)
# results in: ["Mike", "Julia", "Phil"]
```

into something like this

```
kids |> Enum.filter String.contains? "i"
```

Won't work. - What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's very close, you can go with it step by step.

1. Move `kids` "before" `|>`:

   `kids |> Enum.filter(fn(n) -> String.contains?(n, "i") end)`
2. Use [capture operator](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/08/05/understand-capture-operator-in-elixir) to shorten the *filtering* function:

   `kids |> Enum.filter(&String.contains?(&1, "i"))`

Hope that helps!

Comment: I like the second solution a lot: `kids |> Enum.filter(&String.contains?(&1, "i"))`. Reminds me of Mathematica's anonymous functions, for instance: `Map[f[#, 5]&, data]`, where the `&` converts `f[#, 5]` into an anonymous function with one argument, put in `#`

Comment: Just to add to it, if the function accepts one argument (like, eg. [`String.upcase`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#upcase/2), you could even write it like: `kids |> Enum.filter(&String.upcase/1)`. Hope that give you some better feeling around capture operator, @Ugur!

Answer (score 1):

Trying it on iex gives us the error:

```erlang
iex(4)> kids = ["Mike", "Paula", "Julia", "Phil"]                 
["Mike", "Paula", "Julia", "Phil"]
iex(5)> kids |> Enum.filter String.contains? "i" 
warning: parentheses are required when piping into a function call. For example:

    foo 1 |> bar 2 |> baz 3

is ambiguous and should be written as

    foo(1) |> bar(2) |> baz(3)

Ambiguous pipe found at:
  iex:5

** (UndefinedFunctionError) function String.contains?/1 is undefined or private. Did you mean one of:

      * contains?/2

    (elixir) String.contains?("i")
```

The error is because [`String.contains?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#contains?/2) expects 2 arguments and only one was given. Also the second argument to [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) should be a function. So, to get rid of the error you could write:

```erlang
iex(1)> kids = ["Mike", "Paula", "Julia", "Phil"]
["Mike", "Paula", "Julia", "Phil"]
iex(2)> kids |> Enum.filter fn(n) -> String.contains? n, "i" end
warning: parentheses are required when piping into a function call. For example:

    foo 1 |> bar 2 |> baz 3

is ambiguous and should be written as

    foo(1) |> bar(2) |> baz(3)

Ambiguous pipe found at:
  iex:2

["Mike", "Julia", "Phil"]
```

To make the pipeline unambiguous, and in the process get rid of the warning, simply add parentheses around the function call:

```erlang
iex(3)> kids = ["Mike", "Paula", "Julia", "Phil"]               
["Mike", "Paula", "Julia", "Phil"]
iex(4)> kids |> Enum.filter(fn(n) -> String.contains? n, "i" end)
["Mike", "Julia", "Phil"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [comprehensions](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/comprehensions.html) with a filter:

```elixir
for kid <- kids, String.contains?(kid, "i"), do: kid
["Mike", "Julia", "Phil"]
```

Comment: Actually, I am coming from Python and this is how I did it in Python first: `[kid for kid in kids if "i" in kids]`. Python does not favor `map` and `filter` anymore. It favors list comperhensions instead. Also, you can't chain functions / methods in Python elegantly or at all. This is something that I really loved in Ruby, and I love it even more in Elixir.